# 0x98FA2 Unknow function in memory with QEMU

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, qemu, osdev

I'm debugging a 32bits operating system, and to do it I'm using QEMU+GDB.

I'm trying to discover in which moment the code makes an INT 16 to get the keyboard buffer.

I isolated the function that does this, but I can not understant how it does it.

There is a moment that executes a CALL DWORD PTR[EAX] while EAX is pointing to 0x98FA2 (and it jumps to this address).

The think here is that this is not a memory corresponding to the operating system, I don't know why is this code in this point of memory.

I have put a watchpoint to 0x98FA2 to discover who is writting code here. For my surprise, is the QEMU bios, from 0x5b the BIOS is writting this bytes.

Anyone can orient me?

Comment: Well, if the IVT is located at address 0, then the interrupt vector for `int 16h` would be the DWORD at address 58h..5Bh.

Comment: A 32-bit OS is likely not using the BIOS to do keyboard read and writes as BIOS interrupts aren't available while in 32-bit protected mode. They'd have to switch back to real mode and then back to protected mode which makes no sense. 32-bit OSes usually initialize the keyboard controller and then read and write characters directly (and most set up their own interrupt handler and circular keyboard buffer).

Comment: The source to the BIOS that QEMU runs in the guest is freely available, so it would be faster to look at it rather than reverse-engineering it...

Comment: As @MichaelPetch indicated, it seems that the OS have some functions to make the functions of talking with keyboard and tty.
What I don't understand is how it works exactly, do you have any reference where I can get more information about how these controllers work?

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller and https://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard have information.

Comment: ...and the seabios code that accesses the PS2 ports is in this file: https://git.seabios.org/cgit/seabios.git/tree/src/hw/ps2port.c